# libpcap fails to capture packets after upgrading to new linux ethernet driver

Tags: networking, intel, libpcap

I have an old system running a custom 2.6.15 kernel that uses libpcap (version 1.1.1). Recently I've changed my network card with Intel 82575EB chipset that requires me to update the driver to igb.ko (was e1000.ko). After the update, libpcap stop capturing packets. I modified a sample test code from tcpdump website that captures 1 packet and print the header information, libpcap return header.len of 1358 and header.caplen of 42, whereas in e1000 case, both packet.len and packet.caplen returns 1358. I've tried disabling MSI/MSI-X and increase the MTU but nothing works. Is there any other options I need to set to get the igb driver to work with libpcap?

Here's the sample test program (courtesy of tcpdump/libpcap team):

```
#include <pcap.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   pcap_t *handle;                 /* Session handle */
   char dev[20];                   /* The device to sniff on */
   char errbuf[PCAP_ERRBUF_SIZE];  /* Error string */
   struct bpf_program fp;          /* The compiled filter */
   bpf_u_int32 mask;               /* Our netmask */
   bpf_u_int32 net;                /* Our IP */
   struct pcap_pkthdr header;      /* The header that pcap gives us */
   const u_char *packet;           /* The actual packet */

   if (argc <= 1) return(1);
      strcpy(dev, argv[1]);

   /* Find the properties for the device */
   if (pcap_lookupnet(dev, &net, &mask, errbuf) == -1) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't get netmask for device %s: %s\n", dev, errbuf);
      net = 0;
      mask = 0;
   }

   /* Open the session in promiscuous mode */
   handle = pcap_open_live(dev, BUFSIZ, 1, 1000, errbuf);
   if (handle == NULL) {
       fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't open device %s: %s\n", dev, errbuf);
       return(2);
   }

   /* Grab a packet */
   packet = pcap_next(handle, &header);
   /* Print its length */
   printf("packet length [%d]; captured length [%d]\n", header.len, header.caplen);
   /* And close the session */
   pcap_close(handle);
   return(0);
}
```

Comment: I am not really pro in that topic but better tip from amateur than nothing. Is it really that bad, that caplen is only 42? I think that packets can be fragmented so I would expect missing 1316 bytes in next packet. Maybe new network card just handles them in another way or whatever magic could happen inside computer.

Comment: This just an idea: You probably have to show whether you are capturing from the interface or from a .pcap file. If the later holds, then it maybe that you are looking into two different packets. I would propose to use tcpdump to capture a .pcap file. Then you can post-process it with tcpdump and check whether libpcap is the problem, or your code.

Answer (score 0):

Try libpcap 1.4.0, which is currently the most recent release; there's a bug in 1.1.1 that, as I remember, could cause a packet to be supplied with a too-short caplen even though you've supplied a sufficiently-large snapshot length argument to `pcap_open_live()` (which you have - `BUFSIZ` is typically somewhere between 1K and 4K, both of which are bigger than 42, and I think it's 4K on Linux).